# How to use FormatCurrency inside an for loop?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a for loop to write the orderItems fields in html, but i can't concatenate FormatCurrency() function in Write():

this is my script:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");

var orderItems = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Variable.GetValue("@orderItems"));

var baseUrl = Variable.GetValue("@baseUrl");

for (i = 0; i < orderItems.length; i++) {
    var item = orderItems[i];
  
    Write(' <tr>')
    Write('     <td rowspan="3">')
    if (typeof item.productUri != 'undefined' && item.productUri) {
        Write('         <img class="product-image" data-imagetype="External" src="' + baseUrl + '/' + item.productUri + '">')
    }
    Write('     </td>')
    Write('     <td colspan="3">')
    Write('         <p class="product-name">' + item.productName + priceCurrency + '</p>')
    Write('     </td>')
    Write(' </tr >')
    Write(' <tr>')
    Write('     <td>')
    Write('         <span class="product-brand">' + item.productBrand + '</span>')
    Write('     </td>')
    Write(' </tr>')
    Write(' <tr>')
    Write('     <td>')
    Write('      <div>')
    Write('       <div class="product-item column-prod-item">')
    Write('        <div>')
    Write('            <span class="product-volume">' + item.productVolume + '</span>')
    Write('        </div>')
    Write('       </div>')
    Write('       <div class="product-item column-prod-item-min">')
    Write('        <div class="item-quantity">')
    Write('            <span class="quantity">' + item.quantity + ' und</span>')
    Write('           </div>')
    Write('           <div class="item-price">')
    Write('                         <span class="price">' %%=FormatCurrency(' + item.itemPrice + ',"pt_BR")=%% '</span>')
    Write('           </div>')
    Write('          </div>')
    Write('      </div>')
    Write('     </td>')
    Write(' </tr>')
    Write(' <tr>')
    Write('     <td colspan="4">')
    Write('      <p class="space-product-item"></p>')
    Write('     </td>')
    Write(' </tr>')
}
</script>
```

Comment: The solution you have above is very hard to read, and likely harder to maintain. I would simply retrieve the values from the iterated JSON and then either call them directly in the HTML or use SetValue to assign them to an ampscript variable that you can then reference in the loop. Using this many Write statements just to output HTML with dynamic values is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix SSJS and AMPscript blocks that way.  As @JasonHanshaw suggested, I'd use Variable.SetValue() to set AMPscript vars in your SSJS block, then you can just close the script block and use inline AMPscript.

Something like this:

```ampscript
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var orderItems = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Variable.GetValue("@orderItems"));

var baseUrl = Variable.GetValue("@baseUrl");
Variable.SetValue("baseUrl", baseUrl);

for (i = 0; i < orderItems.length; i++) {

    var item = orderItems[i];

    Variable.SetValue("productUri", item.productUri);
    Variable.SetValue("productName", item.productName);
    Variable.SetValue("productBrand", item.productBrand);
    Variable.SetValue("productVolume", item.productVolume);
    Variable.SetValue("quantity", item.quantity);
    Variable.SetValue("itemPrice", item.itemPrice);

    </script>
  
     <tr>
         <td rowspan="3">

            <script runat="server" language="ampscript">
             if not empty(@productUri) then
            </script>

                 <img class="product-image" data-imagetype="External" src="%%=concat(@baseUrl,'/',@productUri)=%%">

            <script runat="server" language="ampscript">
             endif
            </script>
          
         </td>
         <td colspan="3">
             <p class="product-name">%%=concat(@productName, @priceCurrency)=%%</p>
         </td>
     </tr >
     <tr>
         <td>
             <span class="product-brand">%%=v(@productBrand)=%%</span>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
          <div>
               <div class="product-item column-prod-item">
                    <div>
                        <span class="product-volume">%%=v(@productVolume)=%%</span>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="product-item column-prod-item-min">
                    <div class="item-quantity">
                       <span class="quantity">%%=v(@quanity)=%% und</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-price">
                        <span class="price">%%=FormatCurrency(@itemPrice,"pt_BR")=%%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
          <p class="space-product-item"></p>
         </td>
     </tr>
<script runat="server" language="javascript">     
}
</script>
```